# Workbench on Drupal 7 not returning to Draft properly

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, workflow, workbench

I have installed the Workbench module version 7.x-1.2 on my 7.22 Drupal install. Everything is working fine as far as an original author changing the status of a page from "Draft" to "Needs Review" and the page then showing up in an approved users workbench to review. The problem is that if the reviewer finds an issue and then changes the status from "Needs Review" back to "Draft" with some notes and sends it back to the original author, the page DOES NOT show up in the original authors workbench. It actually completely disappears from the original author and doesn't show anywhere. The reviewer can see it in THEIR Drafts tab, but that's it. This obviously isn't right. Has anyone else seen this or have a fix for it? This seems to me to be one of the most basic aspects of the system to not be working correctly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I think I figured this one out. I edited the "My Drafts" view and under Filter Criteria I edited the "User: Current" value and the Realtionship to "author" instead of "revision user". It appears to be working now, but I guess we'll see as time goes on.

Comment: Glad you figured that out. ;)

Comment: I am not sure if that is the right approach. The relationship is there t get the revision informat and I think it should remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

This works well, but it means that if you edit any content it does not appear in your My Edits view unless you are the original author.

This might be what you're after, but for what I needed, I modified your solution to include (revision) User: Current OR (author) User: Current for the My Edits view, so that anything you originally created or at some point edited appears there.